# Multiple Line plot in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
              Crime Type Year Number of Incidents
1  Anti-social behaviour 2010                4139
2            Other crime 2010                2658
3          Violent crime 2010                 832
4               Burglary 2010                 633
5          Vehicle crime 2010                 523
6  Anti-social behaviour 2011                2964
7            Other crime 2011                 372
8          Violent crime 2011                 937
9               Burglary 2011                 657
10         Vehicle crime 2011                 580
11 Anti-social behaviour 2012                2192
12           Other crime 2012                 251
13         Violent crime 2012                 792
14              Burglary 2012                 441
15         Vehicle crime 2012                 383
16 Anti-social behaviour 2013                1504
17           Other crime 2013                  58
18         Violent crime 2013                   0
19              Burglary 2013                 564
20         Vehicle crime 2013                 480
21 Anti-social behaviour 2014                1607
22           Other crime 2014                  86
23         Violent crime 2014                   0
24              Burglary 2014                 559
25         Vehicle crime 2014                 475
26 Anti-social behaviour 2015                1910
27           Other crime 2015                  93
28         Violent crime 2015                   0
29              Burglary 2015                 591
30         Vehicle crime 2015                 579
```

I am looking to make a line plot with a different line for each crime type, with year along the x axis, and number of incidents on the y axis. How could I do this?

Comment: post what you have done so far?

Comment: That's something like "please do this work for me".